# Are there APIs to check media for copyrighted material?

Tags: video, api, music

I'm building a site for a client where he can upload his own videos. One requirement is being able to label videos if they have a copyrighted song in them.

So I'm looking for an API that can fingerprint the audio for any copyrighted material.

Comment: I find really difficult to have such a program. Even nowadays, copyright violation are manually flagged more often than not, plus some checksum validation against known pieces. But copy-paste of material from one video from other for example, is another history.......